# Magento: Add Login/MyAccount Widget in Sidebar

Tags: php, magento

Want to add a Login/MyAccount widget to the sidebar in Magento. Is there an easy helper method I can call to do that?

Basically, want users to be able to login from the sidebar. And if they are logged in that widget space should be taken up by a My Account widget.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
```

Then You can ad this block via `$this->getChildHtml('customer_form_mini_login');`

Comment: Where does this get added?